# Referential and structural equality in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between *referential* equality and *structural* equality
in **Kotlin**?

```
val a = File("/myfile.txt")
val b = File("/myfile.txt")
val sameRef = a === b
```

and:

```
  val a = File("/myfile.txt")
    val b = File("/myfile.txt")
    val both= a == b
```

Comment: i read the doc before,but i can't understand well what's the exact meaning of referential and structural equality

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- **Referential equality** `===` *(also called **identity**)* means that the pointers for two objects are the same. That is to say the objects are contained in the same memory location which leads us to the fact that pointers reference to the same object.

  > **identity:** determines whether two objects share the same memory address
- **Structural equality** `==`, in its turn, means that two objects have equivalent content. You should specify when two objects should be considered equal by overriding the [equals()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/equals.html) method.

  > **equality:** determines if two object contain the same state.

As well as in **Java**, in **Kotlin** there're no specific `equals()` and `hashCode()` generated by default (not considering [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)). Thus, until you've overriden these methods for your class, both `==` and `===` perform identity comparison.